# Runner quits unexpectedly in a Flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, info.plist

When I add this code in my project file `info.plist` then my app started crashing but without it, the app is running well. I tried everything that I know but still I have problem.

I try to connect my project to Facebook for Facebook Login. What can I try next?

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb*************</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>***********</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>****</string>
```